# Virtualize SCO 5v6.0.0 P2V

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, physical-to-virtual, convert

I try to virtualize old SCO server and i Have a little problem with that.

When i try to startup VM i see somethink like that:
[SCO error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvJZb.jpg)

Physical server: HP ProLiant DL380 G5 with six harddisk's ( Combined into raid ) - On this server we have SCO 5v6.0.0

And i Try to virtualize this into Esxi. I do a backup by aomei backupper professional, next i create a virtual machine and recovery sco from backup. I see welcome screen from SCO and after 5 minutes i see error

Anyone do some think like that or have some experience and can help me ?

---

SCO 5v6.0.0 - i found that is SCO openserver 6 propably without any Maintenance Pack's ( I don't know how to check the version correctly i only found command that show this version - and yes i search on google )

> To be honest I'd suggest just installing a modern version of ESXi on a
>   modern server then try to convert the functionality of this existing
>   box over to a VM based on a modern OS

My first thing is to do that :) but unfortunetly I can't. We have a ERP ( 3rd party company implemented it for us ) on this server with very important data.

> The HP DL380 G5 is only supported on ESXi 5.0u3and lower and although
>   I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'SCO 5v6.0.0' the only SCO
>   support with ESXi 5.0u3 is for OpenServer 5 and UnixWare 7.

Yes, but you can choose a compatibility when you create a VM, or I'm wrong ? And by the way I have Esxi 6.5

> That said it appears your problem relates to the VM not providing a HP
>   CCISS compatible virtual disk controller - which it's trying to boot
>   from - you'd need to install vmtools

Can I install vmtools on that VM even system don't boot ?

So many questions :) I just asked if anyone has already virtualized SCO and has some experience in this topic :)

Answer (score 2):

The HP DL380 G5 is only supported on ESXi 5.0u3and lower and although I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'SCO 5v6.0.0' the only SCO support with ESXi 5.0u3 is for OpenServer 5 and UnixWare 7.

That said it appears your problem relates to the VM not providing a HP CCISS compatible virtual disk controller - which it's trying to boot from - you'd need to install vmtools, if available for your OS, and try to make that work. To be honest I'd suggest just installing a modern version of ESXi on a modern server then try to convert the functionality of this existing box over to a VM based on a modern OS - anything else is going to be staggeringly fragile.

Also please note that we make it very clear in our help pages that serverfault is here for those building and supporting supportable systems - both the DL380 G5 and ESXi 5.0u3 are now end-of-service-life, as is I suspect your OS. Please consider this when asking questions in the future.

Comment: The OP posted an answer with a response to your remarks which was converted and appended to the original question by your friendly moderator.